# Iterating over a list to make widgets

Tags: python, variables, widget

I'm currently working on a bit of code using Tkinter, and I've come to a road block that I can't solve with any amount of Google searching.

Essentially, I've got a function that's reading lines from a text file and spitting it out into list. My problem is I don't know how many labels there's gonna end up being, so I set up a counter variable and a for loop.

My question is how would I define a Tkinter widget like so:

```
self.label(counter value here) = Label(self, text = line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usual to do this sort of thing with a list comprehension

```
self.labels = [Label(self, text=val) for val in my_list_of_texts]
```

Now can access them directly by index `self.labels[0]`, `self.labels[1]`, ...

But often you'll be looping over the whole list

```
for label in self.labels:
    label.some_method()
    do_something(label)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for val in my_list_of_texts:
    self.labels.append(Label(self, text = val))
```

I don't quite get what is the problem..

Comment: I've solved my problem, thank you, but I was asking how to create a widget dependent on a variable, like if the counter variable were to be 3, it would be 

`self.label3 = Label(self, text=line)`,

which I finally got around with the `exec` command.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put it into container? Can you show us your answer? (for ex. by answering your own question ;) )

Comment: I'd rather not answer, as I'm not 100% certain it's the best solution.

Comment: That's the reason why it might be worth posting it here - you'll get feedback.

Comment: It would appear that I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question within 8 hours. Sorry for being such a pain, the reason I don't have enough shows.